# How to convert this statement from (LINQ To Object) Criteria To Lambda Expression?

Tags: c#, linq-to-objects

I am quite new to `Linq`. Just wondering how can I express this criteria to Lambda expression?

```
        var query = from person in personList
                    from toy in person.Toys
                    from animal in person.Animal
                    where animal.Name == "Cat"
                    select new
                    {
                        person.Id,
                        toy
                    };
```

I have tried this :

```
var newlist = personList.Select(p => new { id = p.Id, toys = p.Toys });
```

But I have no idea where to put the where clause. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is roughly equivalent:

```
query = personList.SelectMany(p => p.Animal.Where(a => a.Name == "Cat")
                  .SelectMany(a => p.Toys.Select(t => new
                  {
                      p.Id,
                      toy = t
                  })));
```

If you've got [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) you can click on the `λ` tab and see the equivalent lambda syntax for your statements.

Answer (score 0):

something like
 `personList.Where(p => p.Animal.Any(a => a.Name == "Cat")).SelectMany(p => p.Toys, (p1,t) => new { p1.Id, t})`